# $x^2 +x -2 \geq 0$ basic problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $x^2 +x -2 \geq 0$

How do I conclude $x \geq 1$ or $x \leq -2$ algebraically ?

Comment: do you know that $\text{positive} \times \text{positive} = \text{positive}, etc$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1)\geq 0$. Then

$(x+2)\geq 0$ and$ (x-1)\geq 0$ or

$(x+2)\leq 0$ and$ (x-1)\leq 0$

$\Rightarrow x\geq -2$ and$ x\geq 1$ or

$x\leq -2$ and$ x\leq 1$

$\Rightarrow x\geq 1$ or $x\leq -2$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+x-2 = (x-1)(x+2)$. Thus if $-2 < x < 1 \Rightarrow  x - 1 < 0, x + 2 > 0 \Rightarrow  (x-1)(x+2) < 0$, hence it must be true that $x \leq -2$ or $x \geq 1$.

Comment: I just edited it........